# What is the name of the Android icon?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-icons

Is it the standard icon? What is it called? (android.R.drawable.???)
I am referring to the update or refresh icon.

[Icon](http://developer.android.com/images/ui/notifications/activity_indicator.png) (on the left)

Comment: have you looked at [the Android ActionBar icon pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) yet?

Comment: There is a similar icon called "ic_menu_refresh.png" in `path/to/sdk/platforms/android-{api}/data/res/drawable-{screen}/ic_menu_refresh.png`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html doesn't show it, so it's not possible to get it through android.R.drawable

Answer (score 0):

You can get this icon, like @panini said, in the [Android Design Downloads](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) page.
There are two versions, the Holo Light and Holo Dark, and it is the Holo Dark one that is shown in your link. An example of the image is shown in the same page under "Action Bar Icon Pack".